# Get count of values from a column separated by comma

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheet in the format given below.

[image]

```
Required output

a = 3
b = 3
c = 3
d = 3
```

Comment: Use COUNTIFS with wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(A1:A, ",")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This works perfectly. Is there a way we can get a count of two or more values. Like a, b = 2, a, c= 2

Comment: also possible but it depends on your dataset which is unknown to us

Comment: My use case is the same as given above. So to explain a bit member one plays Cricket, Football. member 2 plays Football, Chess. member 3 plays Football, Cricket. Now we want to get count of members who play Football and Cricket.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this a bit more. Thanks

Comment: sure, in B1 you can type your search criterion in comma separated format. then based on number of comma separated items we create generated string of parameters (the JOIN function) within QUERY which will check if B1 is present in A column. then we just use simple COUNTA to convert the output into numbers